# How to abstract stdin/stdout and files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, character-encoding

I'm trying to write a Python script which lets the user to switch between stdin/stdout and files for input/output. But I'm not sure if my implementation is correct:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import fileinput
import sys

from contextlib import contextmanager
from contextlib import redirect_stdout


def foo(file):
    return ''.join([line for line in file])


@contextmanager
def run(input_file, output_file):
    stdin = '-' if input_file is None else input_file
    stdout = sys.stdout if output_file is None else open(output_file, 'w')
    with fileinput.input(stdin) as stdin, stdout:
        with redirect_stdout(stdout):
            print(foo(stdin))
```

1. Is the code managing resources correctly?
2. How can I properly handle character encoding? I'd like to have everything in utf-8.
3. Is there any room for improvement in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to do this way. You don't need to make `run()` itself a `@contextmanager`—all it needs to do is use one (or more, and both `fileinput.input` and `redirect_stdout` are ones already). I'm not sure why you're using `fileinput.input` since there appears to only be one input file involved.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import fileinput
import sys

def foo(file):
    return ''.join([line for line in file])

def run(input_file, output_file):
    stdin = '-' if input_file is None else input_file
    stdout = sys.stdout if output_file is None else open(output_file, 'w')
    with fileinput.input(stdin) as stdin, redirect_stdout(stdout):
        print(foo(stdin))

run('input.txt', 'output.txt')
run('input.txt', None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using `fileinput` because there might be more than one input file. The main objective is to make the script pipe-able. I'm not sure I understand your comment about `@contextmanager`. Are you saying that with the current implementation I don't need `@contextmanager`? And also would you please comment on character encoding?

Comment: I meant that since `fileinput.input()` and `redirect_stdout()` are already both context managers, there's no need for you to also make `run()` one, too. As for encoding, if `stdout` is not being re-directed, you might have a problem depending on what the default encoding for `sys.stdout` is for your OS. For files, you might have to use [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to avoid encoding issues when reading and writing data from/to them depending on what they contain. Instead of asking hypothetical questions here, why don't you try running it and see.